# What should we do with questions with a false premise?

Tags: discussion

This *must* have been asked already, but I can't summon the right search terms to find it.

Suppose a question makes a false premise, but it's well-researched and genuine. "Why is the sky red?" they ask.

What is the correct course of action? Should we answer the question, stating the sky *isn't* red? Is there a more-appropriate action?

Comment: I would comment saying that it was unclear what they are asking because the sky is obviously not red, most of the time, and ask them to provide an example of a situation which could reproduce the issue that they were seeing. Then I would vote to close as off-topic because it's not a programming question (or unclear what you're asking / not reproducible if the real question was otherwise on-topic)

Comment: You're not speaking of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) are you? If you could provide a more concrete canonical example of what you're asking about, we might be able to give you better answers or dup links.

Comment: I don't think it is always off topic, answers of the question may also useful to correct other users that have same false premises or assumptions at future(provide that the false premise is not too unreasonable or fancy).

Comment: "Why is the sky red" can in fact be a reasonable question, with a [reasonable answer](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2012/08/23/why-is-the-night-sky-turning-red/#.VrLF8stOlnE).

Comment: @ff524 - still OT on SO :)

Comment: The XY Problem doesn't quite fit the scenario, but the car-with-square-wheels analogy does. Thanks all.